# Can Sling mappings be restricted to requests with host header

Tags: url-rewriting, aem, sling

I would like to selectively apply [Sling mappings](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) defined in sling:Mapping nodes under /etc/map.publish and can't get the behaviour I would like.

Essentially, I would like the **mapping rule to trigger only when the host header matches** the request.

I am currently using sling:Mapping nodes under /etc/map.publish to map resource paths to short URLs in the response.

So under `/etc/map.publish/http/myapp` I would have the following node:

```
<jcr:root ...>
    jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
    sling:internalRedirect="/content/company/app/en"
    sling:match="app.company.com
</jcr:root>
```

What I would like is that when a user requests:

```
http://app.company.com/content/company/app/en/page.html
```

The urls in the response (when mapped) will return in the form:

```
http://app.company.com/page.html
```

The reason for this difference in inbound and outbound urls is because I have Apache rewriting URLs for different device types.

However, when a request with a different host header arrives, such as:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/company/app/en/page.html
```

I do not want the URLs to be mapped according to that rule.  Right now, it is being mapped to

```
http://app.company.com/page.html
```

It seems as though the mapping is strictly resolves the resource using considering the host/port.  Then when mapping urls during output a "best match" is found and used.  I would like the map() to behave like the resolve() if possible.

Comment: @Tomek and diffa, can you please heve a look into my isuue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662780/how-sling-rewriter-works-clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mechanisms based on `/etc/map`:

1. URL resolver using `resolver.resolve()` responsible for transforming URLs like `http://app.company.com/page.html` into content path, eg. `/content/company/app/en/page.html`
2. Link rewriter using `resolver.map()` method which transforms the content and shortens all links from `/content/company/app/en/page.html` form in `<a>`, `<img>`, etc. to full URL. It will work only if you don't have any regular expressions in apropriate `sling:match` property.

You can use domain name to map/resolve content and eg. create [multidomain environment](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration/), so `http://app.company.com/page.html` will hit one resource and `http://app.company2.com/page.html` will hit another.

However, you can't disable or enable link rewriter depending on the current request host. Eg. if configure mappings as above, the `/content/company/app/en/page.html` content path will always be shortened to `http://app.company.com/page.html`, no matter what host header you have in your request.

Comment: There can be a number of mappings defined.  Do you know if the link rewriter just uses the first mapping it finds with a matching path?

Comment: I'm not sure which mapping will be taken in this case. However, I think each content branch should have a separate set of mappings and they shouldn't overlap, so we don't have to worry about order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure your inbound request is resolved, just add a second mapping to it.

Your mapping would look like this:

```
<jcr:root ...>
    jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
    sling:internalRedirect="[/content/company/app/en,/content,/]"
    sling:match="app.company.com
</jcr:root>
```

Outbound mappings, s.a.  resolver.map(), will use the first applying rule.